# Redhat install python package

Tags: python, installation, package, redhat, system-administration

In the RedHat admin guide it goes to some length to say [that python packages should not be installed with pip as root](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/13/install-python3-rhel#:%7E:text=Do%20not%20run%20pip%20install%20as%20root%20(or%20with%20sudo))

Rather you should enable the python environment using `sc enable` and create a virtual environment. Then install the packages into the virtual environment.

I understand this fine - but I want to centrally install a package, not have every user on a system need to fire up a virtual environment in order to access it.

Does anyone know what the best practice approach on RedHat should be?